# Why was my direct answer to this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, mod-abuse

I answered [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/316859/4512) question with:

> OP has identified it as the JST brand ZH series connector, after a small reminder.

I directly answer what type of connector OP needed identified. It is neither a comment or a request for clarification. Why was it deleted?

Comment: Could you please include that deleted answer [it's only one line] into your meta post?  This would provide more context for users that don't have the privilege to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 3):

The comment was deleted because the system flagged the comment for low quality, it ended up going for review and getting deleted by a mod.

It shouldn't have been deleted as it answers the question, it does not fall into the categories listed below but things don't always function perfectly.

This is the recommendation from the [stack exchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/what-does-the-very-low-quality-flag-mean-in-regard-to-answers) on low quality flagging:

> There are several reasons for flagging answers as "very low quality".
>   They include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Severe formatting issues: If a post can be edited by a third party to improve it to the point of not meeting deletion criteria, you
>     should do so if you are able to. Otherwise, you can use the VLQ flag
>     to indicate that the post is not salvageable. A moderator will then
>     delete the post if it is of poor enough quality. They may also notify
>     the user of the reason for deletion, in hopes they may edit and flag
>     for undeletion.
> - Incomprehensibility: It may be an answer, but it's so bad that it could never be saved through editing.
> - Other severe content problems: This includes answers that don't attempt to answer the question (which can equivilently be flagged as
>     NAA) and answers devoid of content (such as "try jQuery!").
>
> However, the "very low quality" flag should not be applied to an
>   answer if:
>
> - The answer is just incorrect. It is not the job of moderators to deal with answers that are incorrect in some respect. Users should
>     downvote wrong answers and (optionally) leave comments that describe
>     why they are wrong. The answerer would, in the best case, update the
>     answer to fix whatever issues it has, or delete it. We even have a
>     badge for that.
> - It is spam or abusive. Spam and abuse flags are handled differently and carry higher penalties. If a post meets the criteria for one of
>     these flags, you should flag it as such rather than Very Low Quality.
>
> A "very low quality" flag on an answer that is technically incorrect
>   should be dismissed. The moderator may take into account the quality
>   of the answer when deciding to mark the flag as "helpful" or as
>   declined for one of the standard reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is very short with extraneous fluff.  I don't get the point about the small reminder.  I can see that being a reason to delete it since the whole answer is borderline anyway.

Your answer is really:

> This is a JST brand ZH series connector.

That's pretty thin, although I might have left it since it is (apparently) correct and useful.

A better answer would include more information and some evidence that this is really the answer.  A link to the ZH series documentation on the JST site would be useful, and maybe a snippet from the datasheet showing a drawing or picture so that anyone can easily see that there is a good chance this answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Since the O.P. have found the solution himself, he should self-answer and accept.

The deleted post in question is a comment that the O.P. have found the solution himself.

Comment: There is no rule about only op being able to answer...

Comment: It's a statement of fact, including the answer, and presumably posted to begin the process of having the question appear resolved, rather than have it sit around and be churned up every once in a while by the annoy-the-community daemon.

Comment: @Chris  The O.P. have found the answer himself.  The correct course of action in such case is to prompt the O.P. to self-answer.

Comment: No, this is yet one more example of how you really don't understand how things here work, and are long past needing to give up that moderator hat you love to abuse.

Comment: @Chris, so you think he should get the credit for the solution which the O.P. have found himself.

Comment: You forget the part where I directed op to JST in the first place.

Comment: Attaboy, @Passerby .  Waving towards supplier's catalog might make a useful comment.  But that's not sufficient for an answer.

Comment: And that may make a useful comment, if it wasn't for the condescending beginning, an obvious "Be nice" fail.

Answer (score -4):

This is like with a stupid teacher who requires minimum volume for an essay. So if mine is more interesting and contains more information than any other, but is shorter, she will not give me high score. I thought that stupidity was 30 years behind me. Appears not..